# What dimensions would a quantum confinement system have to be for its electromagnetic emission spectrum to be in the radio section?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, material-science, nanoscience, quantum-dots

Just as specific dimensional restrictions on systems that have quantum confinement like quantum dots lead to the tenability of the emission spectrum of such a system, I was wondering how this idea could be applied to other emission spectra, in this case, in the radio frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that even in the case of the quantum confinement in quantum dots, the energy spacing between quantum states is dependent not only on the size of the object but also on the height and stiffness of the potential barrier. For colloidal QDs, it is fair to assume that the walls of the potential well are infinitely high, but it is not the case for the quantum dots embedded in a crystalline material. So you can not make a one-by-one relationship between transition frequency and sizes without referring to the potential barrier height. For instance, radio-frequency radiation can be emitted from the vibrational and rotational degrees of freedom of a molecule. In this case, it is rather the stiffness and height of the potential surface that plays a major role than the sizes of the system. Although the stiffness is related to the amplitude of vibrations which has something to do with an average spatial extent of the system.